# ios5 how to pass prepareForSegue: a UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, segue

I want to pass my UIImageView that has a image loaded into it from clicking a button to a different UIImageView in a different ViewController.

Here is my code

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MY_SEGUE"])
{
    // Get reference to the destination view controller
    ViewControllerName *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

    // Pass the current UIImageView to a different UIImageView in a different view controller
    [vc setUIImageView:UIImageView2];
}
}
```

So far when I run this nothing happens when I load the next view.  I have no Errors.  Do I need to say something in the - (void)viewDidLoad for this to work?

Any tips or suggestions???

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do *something* with the image view in your destination view controller.  You probably want to add the view to your view hierarchy.  You might do it in `viewDidLoad` or in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Im not so sure what you mean by do something.  Do I need to allocate because I'm not sure what to put in my destination view controllers ViewDidLoad or in viewWillAppear

Comment: Never mind I figured it out.  I added [UIImageViewName setImage:UIImageView];