# Passing an animating UIImageView between viewControllers in prepareForSegue:?

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

Based on some earlier questions (ex: [ios5 how to pass prepareForSegue: a UIImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950378/ios5-how-to-pass-prepareforsegue-a-uiimageview)) I was wondering how smooth this technique is, say when doing a modal segue with animated = NO.

I can toss together a test but I imagine someone has already scoped out the performance and practical pitfalls of using this as a transition technique. I would be interested in hearing any details - for example, does the UIImageView animation restart or does it continue apace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass an animating image view to another controller, it looks like the animation continues apace. I can't see any "hitch" in the animation. Going forward with a modal presentation worked fine. I couldn't go back to the first controller, by just dismissing, I had to add the image view back to the view to make that work, and even then it only worked if I turned off auto layout (otherwise I get an error saying it can't install a constraint). So, to go back and forth with modals (with no animation) I had this in the first controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.isFirst = YES;
    NSMutableArray *imgArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 1; i< 41; i++) {
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"New_PICT%04d.jpg",i]];
        if (img) {
            [imgArray addObject:img];
        }
    }
    self.iv.animationImages = imgArray;
    self.iv.animationDuration = 10;
    [self.iv startAnimating];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (self.isFirst) {
        self.isFirst = NO;
    }else{
        self.iv.frame = CGRectMake(48, 48, 48, 48);
        [self.view addSubview:self.iv];
    }
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *sec = segue.destinationViewController;
    sec.iv = self.iv;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the details. So it looks like it might be a viable technique for certain styles of transition. I'm still getting the hang of auto layout now so can't say what that error might be about. As a technique it would be loads more flexible if there was more control over the animation of UIImageView (run backwards, etc.).